# Как исправить ошибку сценария?

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте. В IE выдает [image: такую ошибку]

Скажите, что она означает и как ее исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Открыть html код страницы и посмотреть 17 сроку в которой будет

```
drawFirmMap(39.423189859771355,47.10279785037405);
```

Comment: А, спасибо, все понял, а я думал, что 17-я строка вообще, включая скрипты, а это только хтмл. А не подскажете за одно, почему там у меня текст повыше телефонов и адреса пропал в седьмом эксплорере, что такое? Я то думал, что из-за этой ошибки, оказывается нет, это другая ошибка. Самое непонятное, что только в седьмом пропадает и все, а в остальных нормально...

Answer (score 3):

Ошибку выдает во всех браузерах, просто IE делает это самым некрасивым образом. Если открыть страницу, например, в Chrome, то в консоли будет более понятное описание ошибки:

> *Uncaught ReferenceError: drawFirmMap is not defined*

т.е. данная функция не была определена. И её действительно нет в коде страницы и линкованных js-файлах. Исправляется легко — надо её где-нибудь определить :)

Comment: Да, спасибо, я уже понял насчет этой ошибки. Меня вообще другое беспокоило - почему-то исчез текст повыше телефона и адреса при чем только в IE7 и больше нигде. Я-то думал это из-за той ошибки, оказывается нет, не знаете случайно, что это такое?

Comment: Поставьте zoom:1 для класса .ypages1

Comment: Удивительно, все поправилось! Спасибо! Объясните дилетанту, что вообще произошло?:)

Comment: Это специальный хак для IE6/7. Называется hasLayout. Гугл лучше расскажет.